# Styling GeoServer layer by taking coordinates from feature and plot marker

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, sld

I am trying to style the GeoServer layer. I have the shapefile with multi polygon feature into it and in the attributes, I have the x, y(centroid of each polygon) where I need to plot the marker or circle feature.

How can I get the feature from the shapefile in sld file and draw the marker with respect to it?

Comment: Just use a pointsymbolizer either on your polygons or the centroid point.

Comment: I am not able to figure out. Can you please give an sample sld file

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chit like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [SLD Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/index.html) you can draw a [circle](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#simple-point) or a [graphic](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#point-as-graphic) on a point or the centroid of a line or polygon.

If for some reason you need to use a point created from 2 numeric columns you would need to make use of the [`geomFromWKT`](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#geometric-functions) function to create the point in a [`<Geometery>` block](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/pointsymbolizer.html) of the Symbolizer.